# Occasional Amplitude "Invalid apiKey"

Tags: javascript, analytics, amplitude-analytics

I'm trying to record events using the JS Amplitude API.

The setup instructions are to put code in the `<head>` of pages. 
See [Full instructions here.](https://help.amplitude.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001361248-JavaScript-SDK-Installation)

Since I'm using React, I put the code in `index.html`

The event I'm trying to record is executed on `componentDidMount` on various pages:

```
componentDidMount() {
amplitude.getInstance().logEvent("test_profile_accessed", {page: `${test_info}`});
}
```

However, sometimes the event doesn't record because I get this error:

> [Amplitude] Invalid apiKey. Please set a valid apiKey with init() before calling logEvent()

This error *only happens every once in a while*, with the other times successfully recording.

What is going on? I don't see any documentation about this error anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](https://help.amplitude.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001361248-JavaScript-SDK-Installation#installation) state you have to set API key that you got after creating a project:

> 3. Insert your API Key. Replace API_KEY with the API Key given to you. You can find your project's API Key in your project's Settings page.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    // removed the code that loads the Amplitude JavaScript SDK
    amplitude.getInstance().init("API_KEY");
</script>
```

Above script should be included inside your `index.html` head. Make sure you replace `API_KEY` with your **actual API key**.

Comment: Hey HC - I do have the correct API key entered. The events are currently logging only around 70% of the time right now. The rest is getting the error.

Comment: @MichaelNinh This is important information to add to your question. May be the unreliable/occasional error is caused by API (key) dependent _rate limits_ (requests per day)?

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue with `@amplitude/analytics-browser`. Solved by setting the `serverZone` to the correct zone (EU in my case)

```js
  amplitude.init("YOUR_AMPLITUDE_API_KEY", undefined, { serverZone: "EU" });
```